# Expand in terms of sine and cosine sin 43 cos 61 + cos 43 sin 61

Tags: trigonometry

I solved for the figure of sin 43 and cos 61 and follow the prompts getting my answer 0.9703 I just want to be sure if I did the right step

Comment: How?? What about applying $$\sin(A+B)$$

Comment: Thats the step I followed and I got 0.9703 I just want to be sure

Comment: For any angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$.

Comment: Ok so u mean my answer is correct

Comment: Because thats the fomular I followed

Comment: I assume that you are using degrees, not radians, right?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\sin(104)$ regardless of which units are used, radians or degrees.

In degrees, the OP's attempted answer $0.9703$ is correct. In radians, the answer would instead be $-0.3216$.

Comment: Thanks alot u are of a good help